# How to run a scrapy with a py file

Tags: python, scrapy

Hi i am working on scrapy,  i created a scrapy folder with `scrapy startproject example`
and written spider to scrape all the data from the url, and
I had run the spider using the command `scrapy crawl spider_name`, its working fine and able to fetch data.

But i had a requirement that i need to run the scrapy with a single spider file created i mean a single py file something like

```
python -u /path/to/spider_file_inside_scrapy_folder_created.py
```

Is it possible to run a spider without `scrapy crawl` command after creating a scrapy project folder with spider.py file

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try the [runspider](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/commands.html#runspider) command:

```
scrapy runspider /path/to/spider_file_inside_scrapy_folder_created.py
```

Answer (score 12):

Yes! If you want to do it programmatically instead of invoking the command via Popen, you can run it as follows:

```
>>> from scrapy.cmdline import execute
>>> execute(['scrapy','crawl','dmoz'])
```

Let me know if you have any trouble. I'm used the version that the scrapy docs refer to on Github for testing purposes:

https://github.com/scrapy/dirbot

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply. Actually what my thought is storing the entire path of the spider.py file in the database for example project_folder/project_folder/spider/spider.py and by quering the database for the file path and just running the file with python  spider.py file, because actually i had another single py files written with scraping code using urllib2 etc., that are stored in database and getting the file from database and running directly with python command using os.execute command.

Comment: so finally i want to run a single py file in scrapy so that the entire scraping process should carry on with scraping code

Comment: @Kouripm Looking through the scrapy code, I think the only way to invoke the spider you've set up is through the execute method scrapy.cmdline. If it really needs to be a shell a command, you could always do python -c "from scrapy.cmdline import execute; execute(['scrapy','crawl','dmoz'])"

Comment: To me, this is the correct answer: if one don't misunderstand your question that is :)

Answer (score 4):

I think the answer (if I understand your question) is now to [use the API](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#run-scrapy-from-a-script):

```py
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    # Your spider definition
    ...

process = CrawlerProcess({
    'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)'
})

process.crawl(MySpider)
process.start()
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, first reach to the destination where the xyz.py file is located through command prompt. Then you can write the command :

```
scrapy runspider xyz.py
```

And if you want to save the output, you can write :

```
scrapy runspider xyz.py -o output.csv
```

Or you can save the output in json also

Answer (score 0):

your spider class file:

```
class YouNameSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'youname'
    allowed_domains = ['https://www.YouName.com']
```

create main.py in YouName:

```
from scrapy.cmdline import execute
import os, sys
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
execute(['scrapy', 'crawl', 'youname'])
```